# Highlight current week in row

Tags: reactjs, momentjs

I'm trying to highlight the current week in my grid row, get `NaN` for `currentWeek` and `jsonWeek`:

```
if (this.props.data.startDate) {

            var jsonWeek = moment(this.props.data.startDate, "MM-DD-YYYY").week();

            var now = moment();
            var currentWeek = now.week();

            if (currentWeek == jsonWeek) {

                styles = {
                    backgroundColor: 'yellow'
                };

            }
}
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your issue made me correct mine too...fixed the *NaN* this way..

did you change the **locale** like this?

```
 moment.locale('en',
    {
       week: {
               dow: 1 // Monday is the first day of the week
            }
 });
```

that`s the reason to me, because this will add a week object to internal function *localeData().*

I removed the locale customization and changed all

```
.startOf('week')
```

to

```
startOf('isoweek')
```

to get the mondays working and the week will work as well

Comment: Thanks for the reply

Answer (score 0):

I don't see anything wrong with your code. It's probably a problem with your moment dependency. Check that the version is > 2. It looks like `week` was added in `2.0.0`.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, i'm using `2.10.6`